# magento coupon code exists

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes

I have a quick question on magento coupon code generator. Please see the below method in `core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule.php`:

```
 /**
 * Acquire coupon instance
 *
 * @param bool $saveNewlyCreated Whether or not to save newly created coupon
 * @param int $saveAttemptCount Number of attempts to save newly created coupon
 *
 * @return Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon|null
 */
public function acquireCoupon($saveNewlyCreated = true, $saveAttemptCount = 10)
{
    if ($this->getCouponType() == self::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON) {
        return null;
    }
    if ($this->getCouponType() == self::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC) {
        return $this->getPrimaryCoupon();
    }
    /** @var Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon $coupon */
    $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
    $coupon->setRule($this)
        ->setIsPrimary(false)
        ->setUsageLimit($this->getUsesPerCoupon() ? $this->getUsesPerCoupon() : null)
        ->setUsagePerCustomer($this->getUsesPerCustomer() ? $this->getUsesPerCustomer() : null)
        ->setExpirationDate($this->getToDate());

    $couponCode = self::getCouponCodeGenerator()->generateCode();
    $coupon->setCode($couponCode);

    $ok = false;
    if (!$saveNewlyCreated) {
        $ok = true;
    } else if ($this->getId()) {
        for ($attemptNum = 0; $attemptNum < $saveAttemptCount; $attemptNum++) {
            try {
                $coupon->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                if ($e instanceof Mage_Core_Exception || $coupon->getId()) {
                    die(print_r($e));
                    throw $e;
                }
                $coupon->setCode(
                    $couponCode .
                    self::getCouponCodeGenerator()->getDelimiter() .
                    sprintf('%04u', rand(0, 9999))
                );
                continue;
            }
            $ok = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$ok) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Can\'t acquire coupon.'));
    }

    return $coupon;
}
```

I can see it has 10 attempts by default. However if I generate a code which exists in the database, I get an exception immediately:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:41:"Coupon with the same code already exists.";i:1;s:3513:"#0 /var/www/html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(676)
```

Is there any way to prevent this without touching the core code? And in case the coupon code exists - should there not be another try as there are 10 attempts?

Comment: That's an interesting question. Do you use that method in a custom module ? Because that `acquireCoupon` method is not used anywhere in Magento CE codebase

Comment: Hello, yes I am using acquireCoupon method in my custom extension. So far it does look like there is no way around it.

Comment: Are you on Enterprise ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use that `acquireCoupon` method. Indeed, this method is not used anywhere in Magento CE core code but it's used in EE <del>and I'm afraid it might be an old / unremoved / buggy method. I would be very interested to see why it's here.</del>

If you want to use the mass coupon generator, here is how you should do it:

```
// Load your salesrule
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId);
// Get the coupon mass generator
$generator = $rule->getCouponMassGenerator();
// Set the generator data
$data = array(
    'qty' => 1, //number of coupons to generate
    'length' => 10, //length of coupon string
    'prefix' => "test_",
    'format' => Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC,
    'rule_id' => $ruleId //the id of the rule you will use as a template
);
// Validate the data
if ($generator->validateData($data)) {
    $generator->setData($data);
    $generator->generatePool();
    $generatedCount = $generator->getGeneratedCount();
}
```